# Python 2.7 CSV writer: Writing to a CSV with 1 column and the rest of the data in rows

Tags: python-2.7, csv, numpy

So I'm trying to write the results of some code to an output csv file that contains labels in the first column, and data written by row afterwards. eg.

RXN_ID | ID_1  | ID_2  | ID_3  |
LABEL1 | Dat1  | Dat2  | Dat3  |
LABEL2 | Dat1  | Dat2  | Dat3  |
LABEL3 | Dat1  | Dat2  | Dat3  |
LABEL4 | Dat1  | Dat2  | Dat3  |

Currently I am using

```
VarWriteList = [RxnIDS,RxnXjstar,RxnAjstar]
with open(FileName,'wb') as csvfile:

    EfactorWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for var in VarWriteList:    
        EfactorWriter.writerow(var[0,:])
```

Where the `vars` are numpy arrays containing the numbers I want to write. I have the labels in a separate list from earlier in the code called `Params`

Does anybody know how I can write a column to the CSV and subsequently write rows next to it (so for instance, indexed to write starting at the 2nd column rather than the 1st) ?

Answer (score 0):

For your application it would be good to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
# generate your panda dataframe accordingly.
# I am just brutally making it here for illustration
df = pd.DataFrame({'rxn_id':['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'], 'id1':[1,2,3,4], 'id2':[5,6,7,8], 'id3':[9,10,11,12]})
```

df automatically contains dataframe index as its first column.

```
df
   rxn_id  id1  id2  id3
0  label1    1    5    9
1  label2    2    6   10
2  label3    3    7   11
3  label4    4    8   12
```

But you have option not to save it with `index=False` which is what you want.

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, sep='|') # This will write to file out.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I alter it to have a variable heading input depending on the input from a list in a previous part of the code? And also as well as the variable heading input, it would need a variable label choice which would correspond to different datasets in the previous code?

Comment: When you generate pandas dataframe you can replace 'rxn_id', 'id1', .... to other values read from input.
{'rxn_id':['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'], 'id1':[1,2,3,4], 'id2':[5,6,7,8], 'id3':[9,10,11,12]}

Please ask one thing at a time thru comment. It is not easy to reply thru comment.